# requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.wandb.ai', port=443)

Tags: python, ssl

ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:749)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.wandb.ai', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /graphql (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation
of protocol (_ssl.c:749)'),))

I've already installed ndg-httpsclient, pyopenssl, pyasn1, and it didn't work for me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting. Just a tip, do not put error message on a question title, nobody gets attracted to it. Add a descriptive title and give a detailed explanation of what you are doing. Don't forget do show the formatted code

Answer (score 0):

OK, disconnecting the VPN connection on my device can fix the problem.